# Decrypt liferay passwords

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

Currently playing with liferay and i wish to get the username and password.

i can get the username and encrpyted password, so i need to decrypt the password - i thought i could do this with:

```
Company company;
    try {
        company = CompanyUtil.findByPrimaryKey(user.getCompanyId());
        password = Encryptor.decrypt(company.getKeyObj(), password);
    } catch (NoSuchCompanyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (EncryptorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This however returns with an encryptorexception that is:

```
com.liferay.util.EncryptorException: com.liferay.util.EncryptorException: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

I have posted on the liferay forums aswell, but was hoping someone here may also be able to help - i am currently trying to do this in hook form, would a portlet be a better idea?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Liferay is hashing passwords, so there's no concept "decrypting" the password: It's technically impossible. You can brute force some matching parts, but not just decrypt it.

See some deeper discussion [in the Liferay message boards](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4355935). (This is too much to copy/paste here)

If you've also posted your question there, please post a link from your to this post (and/or vice version) if your thread adds value to the discussion

Answer (score 0):

I thought (or hoped) Liferay uses hashing to encrypt the passwords. In this case, you would have to encrypt the given password using the same method and check against the saved one.

What is your purpose of decrypting the password? This determines in which place you would implement this - hook or portlet.

Comment: i want get it so i can parse it to my kerberos for a kerberised SSO

Comment: In this case I think the way to go would be taking the password entered by the user and authenticate against the Kerberos server. Do not attempt to decrypt those passwords. You should be able to implement your own AutoLogin class and plug it into the LR authentication chain. (As you said you just started playing with Liferay: do you have an existing infrastucture that relies on Kerberos? Otherwise I would recommend to try CAS or any other SSO technology that is already supported by Liferay).

Comment: yes i currently have an infrastucture that relies on Kerberos - i have tried and failed in trying to get the password entered by the user... perhaps i am doing it wrong - any ideas / help guides to do this?

cheers for your help so far

Comment: http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+a+Custom+Authentication+System looks rather promising. Might be slightly different for LR6, but could work as a starting point.